# JAXB workaround for Chameleon XSD imports?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

this is my first question, so please be gentle ;)

I'm stuck with a weird problem. Essentially i get three XSD definitions like the following:

```
PartA.xsd
targetNameSpace="PartA"
include="PartB.xsd"

PartB.xsd
<!-- no namespace definition!!! -->

PartC.xsd
targetNameSpace="PartC"
inlude="PartB.xsd"
import="PartA.xsd"
```

The error pops up, when binding *PartC* via JAXB to Java classes:

- A class/interface with the same name "b.exampleType" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
- This confusing error happened most likely because the schema uses a technique called "chameleon schema", which causes a single definition to be loaded multiple times into different namespaces. See http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=18631 for more about this.

Following the link, i found out, the actual error lies in PartB, which has no namespace declaration! This method is called ***Chameleon Schema***. The defined types in *PartB* will adopt the namesspace of the *importing XSD*.

So in my case, there are two namespaces for the same type:

1. "PartA"
2. "PartC"

And this is, where JAXB breaks down. I haven't found a way to bind *PartC* properly. And (to make things tricky) i have chance to change the original XSD definitions!

Has anyone come across this phenomena or something like that before and has a valid workaround for it?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem using **wsdl2java**:

> WSDLToJava Error: Thrown by JAXB : A class/interface with the same
>   name "Respuesta" is already in use. Use a class customization to
>   resolve this conflict.

But this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699331/jaxb-root-class-rename-using-binding-xml?rq=1) pointed me in the right direction.
Using wsdl2java from CFX you can customize how elements are binded to classes using a binding.xml file.
For example:

```
/Applications/apache-cxf-2.7.13/bin/wsdl2java -b ./src/main/resources/binding.xml -V -d src/main/java -compile -classdir target/classes  http://someurl.wsdl
```

The key is to explain in the binding.xml to name certain xsd element with one especific className to avoid colissions:

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">

  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="./someXsdFile.xsd">
    <!-- Rename the respuesta class to resolve a naming conflict with other Respuesta element already defined-->
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='respuesta']/xs:complexType">
      <jxb:class name="Respuesta2" />
    </jxb:bindings>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Hope this helps to the next person with this problem using wsdl2java. I supose that other tools should allow similar aproaches to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following is available, although it does not provide a lot of detail:

- https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#compiling-xml-schema-how-modularization-of-schema-interacts-with-xjc

Comment: Thanks for the link, but you are right, it's not really detailed. And since i don't have write-access on the schema, i'm stuck. ... Although, maybe i can argue with the schema author on the "In some other cases, the chameleon schema can be argued as a bad schema design, as it duplicates definitions in many places." point.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and the google search landed me here.
Your question is detailed enough and I was able to find the answer,
what I did is put the namespace in PartB.xsd and use XJC to generate the java classes.
I added the following:

> xmlns:ns="http://www.myCompany.com/2009/01/CustSchema"  targetNamespace="http://www.myCompany.com/2009/01/CustSchema"

Comment: Also came across same issue, found my answer just reading that question itself, checked the namespace in all three xsd then put the missing namespace in one of xsd and bingo!

Answer (score 1):

There is one workaround for this problem. More specifically what you have to do is:

1.Define proxy schema (**PartB_proxy.xsd**) for **PartB.xsd** (with no namespace definition) and specify temporary namespace (for example **PartB**):

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="PartB"
        targetNamespace="PartB">
<xsd:include schemaLocation="partB.xsd"/>
```

2.Prepare bindings file (for large schemas this step could be automatized by generating episode file - more details in my article - I've attached link at the end of this post) - this step is required to avoid generating duplicate classes for PartB schema (by default the duplicate classes that come from PartB schema will be generated for PartA and PartC schemas/java packages):

```
<bindings version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <bindings scd="x-schema::partA" xmlns:partA="PartA">
        <bindings scd="~partA:SomeType1">
            <class ref="SomeType1"/>
        </bindings>
        <bindings scd="~partA:SomeType2">
            <class ref="SomeType2"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
    <bindings scd="x-schema::partC" xmlns:partC="PartC">
        <bindings scd="~partC:SomeType1">
            <class ref="SomeType1"/>
        </bindings>
        <bindings scd="~partC:SomeType2">
            <class ref="SomeType2"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

3.Generate JAXB classes using XJC, example Gradle task (I am using Moxy implemetnation but You can use default XJC generator from JDK 8 or standalone JAXB library for newer JDK versions):

```
task generateExampleChameleonSourcesWithMoxy(type: JavaExec) {
classpath = configurations.moxy
main = 'org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.xjc.MOXyXJC'
args '-b'
args 'src/main/resources/example/chameleon/bindings.xml'
args '-d'
args 'src/main/generated'
args 'src/main/resources/example/chameleon/PartA.xsd'
args 'src/main/resources/example/chameleon/PartB_proxy.xsd'
args 'src/main/resources/example/chameleon/PartC.xsd'
```

}

4.Remove proxy namespace (**partB**) from **package-info.java** generated for partB schema:

```
javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package partB;
```

5.Finally You can marshal and unmarshal these XML documents using the **Default Namespace Remapping** technique by:

- defining the default namespace for the types with no namespace:

  ***com.sun.xml.internal.bind.defaultNamespaceRemap*** property (JDK JAXB >=JDK 1.8)
  ***com.sun.xml.bind.defaultNamespaceRemap*** property (External JAXB JDK 1.9+)
- performing marshalling/unmarshalling as usual

Here’s the code that is responsible for that (JDK 1.8):

```
//Initialize JaxbContext
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.defaultNamespaceRemap", "partC");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{SomeType1.class}, properties);
//Unmarshall Message object file from example XML
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Object messageObject =     unmarshaller.unmarshal(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/example/chameleon/Division.xml"));
//Marshall message object back into XML
ByteArrayOutputStream xmlMessageOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(messageObject, xmlMessageOS);
System.out.println(xmlMessageOS.toString());
//Validate output XML with schema
InputStream xmlInputStream = new     ByteArrayInputStream(xmlMessageOS.toByteArray());
Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(xmlInputStream);
SchemaFactory schemaFactory =         SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema =     schemaFactory.newSchema(getClass().getResource("/example/chameleon/PartC.xsd"));
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(xmlSource);`
```

Unfortunately, You have to use different JAXB contexts for JAXB objects coming from **PartA** and **PartC** namespaces. This is required because JAXB default namespace remapping property is set per JAXB context - this way JAXB marshaller/unmarshaller knows how to deal with POJO objects that have no namespace defined (**PartB**).
Nevertheless, I do not think it is problematic as usually all the JAXB contexts are initialized once - during the application startup (in singleton).

To sum up, the workaround described above allows You to use JAXB to marshall/unmarshall XML documents without modifying the chameleon schemas. The proxy XSD file is used only at the beginning - for the process of generating JAXB objects (XJC). The marshalled/unmarshalled XML documents still conform to the original schemas. This technique is useful especially if You are not allowed to modify the schemas. I was dealing with that problem for read-only [NDC](https://www.iata.org/en/programs/airline-distribution/ndc/) standard (set of schemas) in 18.1 version defined by http://www.iata.org.

I've written an article on that topic: **How to deal with Chameleon namespace design in JAXB**. You will find it here: https://medium.com/@pziobron/how-to-deal-with-chameleon-namespace-design-in-jaxb-e36bcc03767d. Hopefully, You will find it useful.