# JAXB Root Class Rename using binding.xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I use the Dali plugin in Eclipse to generate Java classes using an xsd file, which essentially just invokes xjc on the schema file.  I used the advice [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/07/jaxb-xjc-and-nested-classes.html) to resolve naming conflicts by applying an XML binding file to the class generation.  This worked well, but I tried to take it a step further by renaming the root element, and the result was that I lost the XmlRootElement annotation.  I tried using annox to add the root element annotation back in, but I get this error:  Unsupported binding namespace "http://annox.dev.java.net". Perhaps you meant "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"?

Here is my initial binding.xml file (without annox):

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <!-- Force all classes to be generated at the top level, this will potentially cause name conflicts -->
    <jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="mySchema-1.0.0.xsd">
        <!-- Rename the root element -->
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='MyRootClassNameIsReallyLong']/xs:complexType">
            <jaxb:class name="ShorterName"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <!-- Rename the Bar class to resolve a naming conflict -->
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Foo']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='Bar']/xs:complexType">
            <jaxb:class name="FooBar"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

By the way, it's worth noting that the schema file came from a third party, so I have no interest in modifying it.  Likewise, I'd rather not tamper with the generated Java files, so that's why I am interested in the binding xml approach.

Edit (9/11/2013) - Here is the binding XML with annox:

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    version="2.1">
    <!-- Force all classes to be generated at the top level, this will potentially cause name conflicts -->
    <jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="mySchema-1.0.0.xsd">
        <!-- Rename the root element -->
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='MyRootClassNameIsReallyLong']/xs:complexType">
            <jaxb:class name="ShorterName"/>
            <annox:annotate>
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="MyRootClassNameIsReallyLong" />
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <!-- Rename the Bar class to resolve a naming conflict -->
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Foo']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='Bar']/xs:complexType">
            <jaxb:class name="FooBar"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Can you show your binding file with annox?

Answer (score 0):

Annox is an XJC add on, so you in addition to declaring the namespace prefx (`xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net`), you also need to declare it as an `extensionBindingPrefix`.

Your openning tag should then look like this:

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"                 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb 
                                   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
               jaxb:extensionBindingPrefix="annox"
               version="2.1">
```

Comment: I had something like that earlier, but I had to take it out because Eclipse gives me the following error: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'jaxb:extensionBindingPrefix' is not allowed to appear in element 
 'jaxb:bindings'.

Comment: Are you setting `extension` option for the xjc compiler to true?

Comment: As noted in the question, I am using the Dali Eclipse plugin to do the XML generation.  The error that I am referring to is in the form of red squigglies.  Do you know how to make Eclipse happy here?

Comment: Besides, I was not convinced annox was alive and kicking, since going to http://annox.dev.java.net in a browser returns absolutely nothing.